# how to Json Parsing from soap web service in android

Tags: java, android

```
String res=anyType{VisitPlan=anyType{City=Ambala; EmployeeId=1; RouteNumber=2; SpokeCode=SPK01; }; }

    JSONObject _myjobject = new JSONObject(res);

        String name = _myjobject.getString("VisitPlan=anyType");

        JSONObject _myjobject1 = new JSONObject(name);

        String t = _myjobject1.getString("City");
```

After Soap Request i am getting response i want to parse and get value of City ,EmployeeId  and Routenumbervalue. But i am unable to parse data  i am trying according to given code but i am unable to get value.

Comment: Your `json` is not correct if you getting that `json` or else post correct `json`.

Comment: SOAP usually does not talk JSON, but XML